# UnicodeEncodeError when trying to add text to a new element in xml

Tags: python, xml, wordpress, unicode, lxml

I've been stuck for the past several hours trying to get past this problem.  I'm having a hard time from trying to read the documentation and the existing forum posts to address this issue.  So I thought I'd give this place a try as a last ditch effort to solve this before giving up.

Basically, the task at hand is to open up a file (actually many files) full of text that I want to put in a new XML element.  The text file was actually created using Python scripts so it handled UTF-16 and UTF-8 nicely.  But it seems that whenever I try to bring the text contents into memory to put into a new xml tag (as opposed to write out to new text files like before), I get thrown the following error messages:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\Users\Johnny\My Documents\PythonSandbox\websiteMigrationScripts\createXmlFile.py", line 87, in <module>
root[k][directionsBodyIndex].text = '<![CDATA[' + "".join(directionsBuffer) + ']]>'
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 1031, in lxml.etree._Element.text.__set__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:55337)
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._setNodeText (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:24657)
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 699, in lxml.etree._createTextNode (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:24506)
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 1431, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:32293)
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udc92' in position 1862: surrogates not allowed"
```

My script looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, codecs
import imageFilesSub
import utf16FilesList
import openpyxl, lxml
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string

# First get the list of files to parse
filesDir = r'K:\Users\Johnny\My Documents\_World_of_Waterfalls\Website\tier 2 pages\tier 3 pages\tier 4 pages'
filesInDir = os.listdir(filesDir)
filesOutDir = r'.\blogsToParse'
filesToParse = []
for file in filesInDir:
    if (file.endswith('-template.html')) and not('travel-blog' in file) and not('accommodations' in file) and not('best-time-to-visit' in file) and not('activities' in file) and not('how-to-get-there' in file) and not('planning-and-preparing' in file) and not('restaurants' in file) and not('which-side' in file) and not('books-and-maps' in file):
        filesToParse.append(file)

# Then get a list of (unique) slugs that represent a unique row entry in the WoW Database
wowDatabaseDir = r'K:\Users\Johnny\My Documents\_World_of_Waterfalls\WordPressSite'
wowSpreadsheet = r'WoW Database for WP.xlsm'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(wowDatabaseDir + '\\' + wowSpreadsheet, data_only=True)
sheet = wb.active

# the following loop returns to maxRow the highest non-empty row
maxRow = 1  # openpyxl indexes from 1 not 0
for i in range(1, sheet.max_row): 
    if sheet.cell(row=i, column=33).value is None:
        pass
    else:
        maxRow = maxRow + 1

# now make a list containing the directory names of the writeups
writeupDirs = []
slugList = []
for i in range(3, maxRow + 1):
    writeupDirs.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=18).value)
    slugList.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=33).value)

from lxml import etree

xmlFile = 'WoW Database for WP 2017-01-01.xml'
data_file = wowDatabaseDir + '\\' + xmlFile
tree = etree.ElementTree(file=data_file)
root = tree.getroot()

k = 0
for element in root:
    try:
        element.attrib[root[k][0].tag] = root[k][0].text  # this puts Entry_No as an attribute of Row
        element.attrib[root[k][1].tag] = root[k][1].text  # this puts Waterfall Name as an attribute of Row
        root[k].append(etree.Element("Introduction_Body"))
        root[k].append(etree.Element("Directions_Body"))

        # need to go through some hoops and hurdles just to find the index of the desired tag (there must be a better way)
        children = []
        for child in root[k]:
            children.append(child.tag)
        fileDirIndex = children.index('File_directory')
        postSlugIndex = children.index('Post_Slug')
        introFilePtrIndex = children.index('Introduction_File_Ptr')
        introBodyIndex = children.index('Introduction_Body')
        introFile = wowDatabaseDir + '\\' + root[k][fileDirIndex].text + '\\' + root[k][introFilePtrIndex].text
        if root[k][postSlugIndex].text in utf16FilesList.utf16List:  # check the slug for unicode special handling
            inFile = open(introFile, 'r', encoding="utf-16", errors="surrogateescape")  # utf-16 works for Chinese, but not anything else
        else:
            inFile = open(introFile, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="surrogateescape")
        introBuffer = []
        for line in inFile:
            introBuffer.append(line)
        root[k][introBodyIndex].text = '<![CDATA[' + "".join(introBuffer) + ']]>'
        inFile.close()

        directionsFilePtrIndex = children.index('Directions_File_Ptr')
        directionsBodyIndex = children.index('Directions_Body')
        directionsFile = wowDatabaseDir + '\\' + root[k][fileDirIndex].text + '\\' + root[k][directionsFilePtrIndex].text
        if root[k][postSlugIndex].text in utf16FilesList.utf16List:  # check the slug for unicode special handling
            inFile = open(directionsFile, 'r', encoding="utf-16", errors="surrogateescape")  # utf-16 works for Chinese, but not anything else
        else:
            inFile = open(directionsFile, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="surrogateescape")
        directionsBuffer = []
        for line in inFile:
            directionsBuffer.append(line)
        root[k][directionsBodyIndex].text = '<![CDATA[' + "".join(directionsBuffer) + ']]>'
        inFile.close()
    except IndexError:
        pass
    k = k+1
```

The offending text file (at least the first one flagged) looks like this:

```
<div class="ad-right">[adrotate banner="17"]</div>

Wapama Falls sits in Hetch Hetchy, which is in the remote northwest corner of Yosemite National Park.  We generally drive up to Yosemite Valley from Los Angeles before getting up to Hetch Hetchy so we'll describe this route first.  It typically takes us about 6 hours to make the drive from <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20014181&aid=825833" target="_blank">Los Angeles</a> to Yosemite Valley.  We normally go from <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20014181&aid=825833" target="_blank">Los Angeles</a> to <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20013079&aid=825833" target="_blank">Fresno</a> via the I-5 and Hwy 99, then through <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20014886&aid=825833" target="_blank">Oakhurst</a> and <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20016735&aid=825833" target="_blank">Wawona</a> via the Hwy 41.  Once in Yosemite Valley, we'd drive west towards the Big Oak Flat Road where the Hwy 120 and Hwy 140 junction.  Then, we'd drive uphill on the Hwy 140 towards the Big Oak Flat Entrance (the Northwest Entrance), where we'd leave the park. 

From the Big Oak Flat Entrance on the Big Oak Flat Road (Route 120), we'd shortly have to turn right at the signed turnoff for <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20014336&aid=825833" target="_blank">Mather</a> and the Evergreen Road.  Then, we'd follow Evergreen Road for 7.5 miles to its junction with Hetch Hetchy Road in <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20014336&aid=825833" target="_blank">Mather</a>.  Turning right onto Hetch Hetchy Road, we'd follow it to the parking lot by the O’Shaughnessy Dam after about seven miles.  On the way, we'd have passed through another entrance fee station.  The two-lane road was a bit narrow in places so we had to drive slowly.  Eventually, we'd reach a car park next to the dam.  The drive from Yosemite Valley to the car park at the O'Shaugnessy Dam took us less than 90 minutes.

From <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20015732&aid=825833" target="_blank">San Francisco</a>, we'd drive east towards <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20015274&aid=825833" target="_blank">Pleasanton</a>, then continue east on the I-205 towards the Hwy 120 passing through <a rel="nofollow" href="    http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20013298&aid=825833" target="_blank">Groveland</a> and eventually through the town of <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20014336&aid=825833" target="_blank">Mather</a>.  Once we were east of <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=20014336&aid=825833" target="_blank">Mather</a>, we'd follow the road to the O'Shaugnessy Dam as described above.  Overall, this drive would take around 4 hours without traffic.
```

This happened to be the 35th record being processed so it was successful in parsing and populating into the modified XML 34 prior records.  The files are similar text files (basically text files with HTML markup and some WordPress shortcodes).

So that's what's frustrating me.  I don't understand what's so different about this 35th file versus the prior 34 files.  I'm also not sure how the illegal character got in there in the first place nor how to get past it.

Any help from the community would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `for ii in range( len( introBuffer)): print( ii, ':'.join(introBuffer[ii:ii+1]))` could narrow (vaguely specified) position 1862 of reported low surrogate `'\udc92'`